# Performance Impact Associated with Functions vs Properties

Tags: swift

From a performance standpoint, consider the following code:

```
var someBool: Bool {
    get {
        //in theory a function here
        return true
    }
}

var anotherBool: Bool = {
    //same function here
    return true
}()
```

Assuming both use the same function to calculate the boolean return, is there any sort of performance benefit from using one versus the other? Is there a recommended approach to consider?

Comment: The latter is a closure, which will capture its values if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
var anotherBool: Bool = {
  //same function here
  return true
}()
```

is a **closure** it's execution happens the first time then the value stored inside `anotherBool` when you call it again , while this

```
var someBool: Bool {
   get {
       //in theory a function here
       return true
   }
}
```

is a **computed property** where every time to write this var it's get is called and execution happens every time you call , so if the content is dynamic use computed property if not then the closure is sufficient as if you used computed it will have performance problem of running same code again that assumed to produce the same result